# how do I output a variable after POST request in node.js?

Tags: node.js, postman, backend

I have created a table called 'orders' in which the field 'order_id' is a primary key. I want to display the value or this order_id after the table is created from post request.

```
 return Orders.create(order).then(function () {
    console.log("Order saved to DB.")
    
      res.status(201).json({ 
        status:"VB100",
        
        
        message: "Order saved Successfully at",
        
        });
    });
```

Comment: whcih orm are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what orm you're using, but does it have a return type?

```
return Orders.create(order).then((res) => console.log(res));
```

Do you get any information about the object returned?
If so, use it in the .then

Or you can make the method async and await the request

```
let res = await Orders.create(order);
```